# I have been trying to create a new react project with npx create-react-app, but I am getting an error

Tags: reactjs

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\myapp.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...+g6qNdDLTEelbre6dbfGb'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-05T03_05_27_161Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test
Done.
```

Comment: Run ***npm cache clean --force** then try again.

Answer (score 1):

please run the following command in Command Line:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
create-react-app <project Name>
```

if you still getting the problem, uninstall the old and download new and remove all npm folders.

if still didn't help, you can switch from `npm` to `yarn`

```
npm install -g yarn

// Method 1

yarn global add create-react-app

create-react-app <projectname>

// Method 2 work on yarn 0.25+

yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: the first solution didi not work, but i installed yarn, the problem  now is when i type create-react-app myapp,i get 'create-react-app  is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: `yarn create react-app my-app` run this command, it will work! don't delete npm